# Проблема с CORS

Tags: rust, actix-web

Есть такой код:

```
use actix_web::{web, HttpResponse, Result};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyObj {
    name: String,
}

async fn index(obj: web::Path<MyObj>) -> Result<HttpResponse> {
    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(MyObj {
        name: obj.name.to_string(),
    }))
}

#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {

    use actix_web::{App, HttpServer};

    HttpServer::new(|| App::new().route(r"{name}", web::get().to(index)))

        .bind("127.0.0.1:8088")?
        .run()
        .await
}
```

Он работает нормально и если зайти, например на такую страницу c локалки - можно увидеть следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я пытаюсь из другого приложения(на локалке) отправить запрос к вышеупомянутой странице
и получаю следующие ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос:
Какое самое простое решение существует в данном случае, что бы дать доступ к запросу из другого приложения?
Примеры которые находил в интернете не удавалось интегрировать(без ошибок) в текущую реализацию.

Comment: А адаптировать пример из документации не пробовали? вот из этой https://docs.rs/actix-web/0.5.7/actix_web/middleware/cors/index.html

Comment: да. Пробовал - и получилось уже только после публикации поста.
(там надо было пару скобок удалить и все заработало.)